# How to replace dataframe values based on other columns and create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a below data frame and I need to check the values of all the columns and make sure they are not updated.

I joined two data frames based on the key and have to compare two DataFrames columns like custname,phone,email and create an new DataFrame where the records where updated and values where replaced.

For Example  -:

Below dataframe custid z have email address was updated since email != email_update and email is not null we need to create a new data frame with replace value and action columns.

df1 (newdata)

```
custid   custname    email              phone
 x         tina     z.gmail.com        345-345-3456
 y         mina     z1.gmail.com       445-345-3456
 z         zina                                 555-345-3456
```

df2(olddata)

```
custid   custname    email              phone
 x         tina     ze.gmail.com        345-345-3456
 y         mina     z1.gmail.com       315-345-3456
 z         zina     z3@gmail.com       555-345-3456
 q         pina     z4@gmail.com       233-456-3456
```

df3

```
custid   custname    email              phone                    Action
 y         mina     z1.gmail.com       445-345-3456               Update
 x.         tina     z@gmail.com      345-345-3456               Update
 q         pina     z4@gmail.com       233-456-3456               Insert
 z.         Zina                             555-345-3456.               None
```

Expected output-:

Python code to compare two DataFrame.

I am trying to compare two DataFrame to get the difference for insert ,update and delete.

I am able to figure out the insert and delete part but unable to get the update rows .

```
   def compare_data(df,df1):
    
   df["Key"] = df["Custid"] + df["Custname"] 
   df1["Key"] = df1["Custid"] + df1["Custname"] 
   
   #########Insert Rows################################################
   df_result =  pd.merge(df1,df,on = 'Key', how = 'inner',suffixes=['', '_update'])
   df3 = df1[~df1['Key'].isin(df_result['Key'])]
   #########Delete Rows################################################
   df4 = df[~df['Key'].isin(df_result['Key'])]
   ###############################################################
```

Things I tried

```
  df5 = pd.concat([df,df1]).drop_duplicates(subset = ['Privilege'],keep= False)
```

But its not working and rows stay there.

Comment: Could you give us your python code? It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: For one single `custid_key` the `custname_updated` is containing a value, even though the `email,  phone` did not get changed. So is the conditional column only the email?..please post the code for the creation of DataFrame.

Comment: Shouldn't the email in the updated dataframe be "z3..."?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need merge, just subset:

```
df[df['email'] != df['updated_email']][['custid_Key', 'custname', 'email', 'phone']].assign(action='updated')
```

For all fields:

```
df[(df[['custname', 'email', 'phone']] != df[['custname_updated', 'email_updated', 'phone_updated']]).any(axis=1)][['custid_Key', 'custname', 'email', 'phone']].assign(action='updated')
```

Comment: I get below error ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['action'] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].ne(df.iloc[:, 4:7].values).any(axis=1) \
                              .replace({True: 'updated', False: ''})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  custid_Key custname         email         phone custname_update  email_update  phone_update   action
0          x     tina   z.gmail.com  345-345-3456            tina   z.gmail.com  345-345-3456
1          y     mina  z1.gmail.com  445-345-3456             NaN  z1.gmail.com  445-345-3456  updated
2          z     zina  z2.gmail.com  555-345-3456            zina  z3.gmail.com  555-345-3456  updated
3          q     pina  z4.gmail.com  233-456-3456            pina  z4.gmail.com  231-456-3456  updated
```

**Another proposition**:

```
>>> df[['custid_Key']].join(
        df.iloc[:, 1:4].ne(df.iloc[:, 4:7].values)
                       .rename(columns=lambda c: f'is_{c}_updated')
)

  custid_Key  is_custname_updated  is_email_updated  is_phone_updated
0          x                False             False             False
1          y                 True             False             False
2          z                False              True             False
3          q                False             False              True
```

Comment: @aditya. I updated my answer. Can you kindly check it, please?

Comment: @ corralien the second proposed solution works but instead of true /false I have to show values from new data df1.if df1 is null and df2 have value then don’t update keep as is.

Comment: @ corralien get this error "Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape "
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (88, 11): given (88, 0)